# What's the point of showsReorderControl?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've got a `UITableView` instance and implemented:

```
tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:
```

After that I can see all my cells with reorder controls.

Apple's header says:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL showsReorderControl; // default is NO
```

If the default value is `NO` why am I seeing the reorder controls?

**Update:**
I've also checked the value of property in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` right after when the cell is created:

```
(lldb) p [c showsReorderControl]
(BOOL) $1 = NO
```

Comment: Um, showing the reorder controls by setting it to `YES`, perhaps?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. "What is showsReorderControl used for" seems like a self answering question.

Comment: Sorry for that. Hope it's better. Now there's just one clear question.

Comment: The header comment might be out of date - did you log the value to see if it really is no?

Comment: @DavidH That's a great idea. Will do it soon (can't right now).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you return YES from `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:`, it does the same thing as setting the `showsReorderControl` to YES.  These are just two different ways to enable the reorder control.

In fact, there is a third way - let's never complain that we don't have options! ;) From the documentation of `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:`:

> This method allows the delegate to specify that the reordering control
>   for a the specified row not be shown. By default, the reordering
>   control is shown if the data source implements the
>   tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: method.

Comment: I see. A very good explanation, thanks a lot! And a subquestion - what would be a reason to change `showsReorderControl` directly?

Comment: Honesty, I can't think of a situation where that would be warranted. My guess is that it's possibly used by the tableView after our delegate methods have returned, during the redrawing of a cell.

Comment: I just did a quick test. The cell being moved has `showsReorderControl` set to YES, by the time `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` is called.

Comment: Very much appreciated. Everything's clear now. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: how can i allow reordering but hide the control at the same time ?

Answer (score 2):

By reading the current Apple docs, it seems `showsReorderControl` has no use at all.

[UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/showsReorderControl)

> For the reordering control to appear, you must not only set this property but implement the UITableViewDataSource method tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:.

[UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:)

> By default, the reordering control is shown if the data source implements the tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: method.

From this documentation I conclude that:

1- The only way to show the reordering control is by implementing `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`, which shows the control in all cells.

2- If you want a cell to *not* display the control, you must return NO from `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:`

3- `showsReorderControl` has no control on wether or not the reorder control is shown.

Comment: From wrangling with the documentation, I think the idea is: if you have a cell that is movable, but you don't want it to have the "grippy" control displayed, you can turn it off. Although if you do that, I'm not sure how you can move anything, because the control is the affordance for picking up the cell.